# Passing data from JSP to Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I am passing data to my servlet through the jsp in this way:

```
<a href="DetyraServlet?action=listDetyra&firstName=<c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>">Something</a>
```

So I am passing the firstName parameter from my bean class (if I am correct). Now I want to pass the firstName through the session.getAttribute("username");
So I want to do something like this:

```
<%  
    String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");  
%>
```

and then

```
<a href="DetyraServlet?action=listDetyra&firstName="<%=user%>">Something</a>
```

But I am getting errors when I try this. Can anyone please tell me what is my bad?

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: If you have the "user" attribute in session, why would you want to pass it in request? Your intent makes no sense and makes your application weak: a malicious user could delete data and change the username in the queryString, this can be easily done with a proxy tool like Burp Suite. The best solution will be to not pass the session data through queryString never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this,

`<a href="DetyraServlet?action=listDetyra&firstName=<%=user%>">Something</a>`

removed the extra " (double quote)

As mentioned by a comment, you need not pass a session variable to your own servlet(same server). You can do the session.getAttribute in servlet code itself.

Comment: The code is still not working. But thank you because you gave me an idea to do it through servlets :)